# How could I see log.txt file on azure cloud service

Tags: log4net, azure-cloud-services

I have azure cloud service project and I am using **Log4net** for logging. Everything running perfectly fine but I am unable to see **log.txt** file after host the project.
Is it any possible way to get that file? Please suggest

Comment: Use [remote desktop](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop/)